# How to filter the search to allow me to find data with upper case?

Tags: angular, typescript

This code allows me to search for any lower case data but when I enter upper case, those data doesn't show up.

```
applyUserFilter(event: Event) {
const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value.trim().toLowerCase();

this.dataSourceUserNonFiltered.filterPredicate = (data: User, filter: string) => {

const email = data.email.toLowerCase().includes(filter);

const status = data.status.toLowerCase().includes(filter);

const role = data.role.toLowerCase().includes(filter);

return email || status || role;

};

this.dataSourceUserNonFiltered.filter = filterValue;

if (filterValue) {

this.dataSourceUserFiltered.data =
this.dataSourceUserNonFiltered.data.filter(user => user.email.includes(filterValue))

}

else {

this.setUserDefaultListValue();

}

this._cdr.detectChanges();

}
```

I've already searched in Google and ChatGPT but none of them seemed to work with my case. I've also tried other syntax to make it work and the one that I've gotten far is to search data with upper cases only which is the reverse of the current progress.

Answer (score 0):

When you use MatTableDataSource, see the [API](https://material.angular.io/components/table/api#MatTableDataSource) and you want to apply a filter you should use the property filterPredicate, not change the filteredData

filterPredicate it's a function with two arguments, the "data" (one element of the array) and the "string" you want to use as filter. Material angular loop over this function in order to show or not the element in the table

```
myFilterFunction=(data:any,filterValue:string)=>
{
    return data.email.includes(filterValue)?true:false
}
```

And when you change the property `filter` of the dataSource, Material Angular execute the function

```
  applyFilter(event: Event) {
    const filterValue = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).value;
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
```

Then we need indicate to Angular that our MatTableDataSource use this function. We make it when we create the dataSource

If I imagine you have a service that received the data

```
this.dataService.getUser().subscribe((res:any)=>{
   this.dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(res);
   //here
   this.dataSource.filterPredicate = this.myFilterFunction;
})
```